# Proof of de Morgans' law: For any sets $X$ and $Y$, $\overline{X\cup Y}= \overline{X}\cap\overline{Y}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For any sets $X$ and $Y$, $\overline{X\cup Y}= \overline{X}\cap\overline{Y}$  [<s>Sorry, the hat should be a horizontal bar</s> ]

Same as the last two questions - this set theory stuff just isn't my walk in the park. Last question in my proofs homework, similar to both other questions I posted, not exactly the same How would I approach it?

Comment: Are you trying to prove that the complement of $(X\cup Y)$ is (the complement of $X)\cap($ the complement of $Y)$?

Comment: Absent any definition, we don't know that $\widehat{Y}$ means. It possibly means complement, but you can't really define the complement without a third set, $U$, the universe in which you are working.

Comment: Didn't you just post this??

Comment: No the other question was slightly different

Comment: Both your questions refer to de Morgans' law, thus you should have posted them as one question. Also, the MathJax/ LaTeX command for bar is `\bar` for a short $\bar X$ and `\overline` for a longer $\overline{XYZ}$

Comment: I don't know if I quite agree with @Alex that you should have posted the two questions together. But the answer to one is almost immediately extrapolated to an answer for the other.

Answer (score 1):

If your definition of $\hat{X}$ is the compliment of $X$, then here is the proof (I will denote the compliment of $X$ by $X^c$). If not, then ignore the next few lines.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be subsets of $Z$. First let's show that $(X\cup Y)^c\subset X^c\cap Y^c$. Let $z\in (X\cup Y)^c$. Then $z\notin X\cup Y\Rightarrow z\notin X , z\notin Y$ which of course means $z\in X^c \cap Y^c$.

Similarly, if $z\in X^c \cap Y^c$ then $z\in X^c$ and $z\in Y^c$ meaning that $z\notin X \cup Y$ and hence $z\in (X\cup Y)^c$. This shows the reverse containment.

In the future, when you are trying to prove two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal, you can prove $A\subset B$ and $B\subset A$.